# Importing videos into an iPod touch

Tags: video, itunes, ipod-touch, import

I have a brand new latest model of an iPod touch. Is there any way to import music videos or tv shows into it, that i've downloaded over the internet with/without iTunes? I can't figure out this iTunes thing. It doesn't seem to let me import videos from my hard disk. Wants me to connect to some iStore or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be able to import, or just drag and drop, video files into your iTunes Library, they have to be the correct format. Download [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), there is a version for both Windows and Mac. When you run it, select the video file you want to use as the source. Then on the list on the right side select iPhone/iPod touch and it will set up all the correct settings. Choose where you want the file to end up and then start it up. When it is done the resulting file can be used directly in iTunes and it will allow you to sync it to your iPod touch.